# Search if line exists from one file to another file

Tags: python

I want to check if content in a is in content b.
For each item, I want to check if content in a is located in b(regardless of order).

I can do something like below, but it has to match even the ordering. What's best way to go one by one and print out true if item in a.txt exists in b.txt?

```
f1 = open("a.txt").read().split("\n")
f2 = open("b.txt").read().split("\n")

for line in f1:
    print f1
for line in f2:
    print f2
print f1 == f2
```

a.txt

```
apple
tomato
green
peach
stack
flow
chance
```

b.txt

```
stack
peach
blue
green
tomato
wax
```

result

```
apple -> false
tomato -> true
green -> true
peach -> true
stack -> true
flow -> false
chance -> false
```

Answer (score 2):

Regardless of order? Use a set!

```
with open('a.txt') as f_a, open('b.txt') as f_b:
    a_lines = set(f_a.read().splitlines())
    b_lines = set(f_b.read().splitlines())
for line in a_lines:
    print(line, '->', line in b_lines)
```

Output

```
tomato -> True
peach -> True
chance -> False
green -> True
apple -> False
stack -> False
flow -> False
```

Answer (score 0):

This will work for you.

```
with open('a.txt') as f, open('b.txt') as g:
        bLines = set([thing.strip() for thing in g.readlines()])
        for line in f:
            line = line.strip()
            if line in bLines:
                print line, "->", "True"
            else:
                print line, "->", "False"
```

## Output

```
apple -> False
tomato -> True
green -> True
peach -> True
stack -> True
flow -> False
chance -> False
```

Comment: Using a `set` would allow `if line in bLines` to operate quicker

Comment: Nice!  Added your suggestion

Comment: Well, I provided my own answer anyways :)

Answer (score -1):

```
for line in f1:
    if line in f2:
        print("true")
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.